# Replace null with auto incremented unique values for all rows in a spark dataframe and all duplicate rows should have same unique_id value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am new to pyspark need help on below scenarios.

For a dataframe :

i)I want to generate unique values for unique_id column whose range should starts from 3000000.
ii) The unique_id value should be same for all the duplicate rows.

input -->

+--------+-----------+------+
|g_id    | c_id  |unique_id |
|  1     | 8     | null     |
|  1     | 8     | null     |
|  4     | 4     | null     |
|  5     | 6     | null     |
|  2     | 1     | null     |
+--------+-------+----------+

output -->

global_id comp_id unique_id

+-----+---+----+-----------+
| g_id |  c_id | unique_id |
|  1   |      8| 3000000   |
|  1   |      8| 3000000   |
|  4   |      4| 4384994   |
|  5   |      6| 3748484   |
|  2   |      1| 3674849   |
+---+---+------+-----------+

Here is what I have tried to do so far :

```
get_gouped_df = Window.partitionBy("g_id","comp_id").orderBy("unique_id")

assign_unique_id = df.withColumn("unique_id", when(row_number().over(get_gouped_df) == 1, 
                                                               monotonically_increasing_id())
                                                              .otherwise(checkglobalDF.unique))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
case class A(g_id: String, c_id: String)

import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Seq(A("1","8"),A("1","8"),A("4","4"),A("5","6"),A("2","1")).toDF
      .withColumn("unique_id", lit(3000000)+rank().over(Window.orderBy($"g_id", $"c_id")))
      .show(false)
```

Output :

```
+----+----+---------+
|g_id|c_id|unique_id|
+----+----+---------+
|1   |8   |1        |
|1   |8   |1        |
|2   |1   |3        |
|4   |4   |4        |
|5   |6   |5        |
+----+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rank() function and then add 3000000 to that column.